# C++ Service Example - Unicode conversion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, service

I found a very detailed example of how to work with services on Windows. (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppWindowsService-cacf4948)

It works fine on its own but I need to apply it to one of my existing projects and here is the problem. The example given by Microsoft used Unicode (set in Visual Studio project settings) but my project uses "Multi-Byte Character Set". Using the example code in my project causes many compatibility related problems with

Now, I need to modify the example from Microsoft to work with "Multi-Byte Character Set" but I don't know if its even possible.

I'm not going to paste any code here as its pasted on the Microsoft website and easy to view. I don't see the point of explaining my own project as the issues are with Unicode formatting only.

---

**TL:DR** Got 2 projects - One using Unicode, other using "Multi-Byte Character Set". Need to merge them together. What is the best way?

---

Edit: Im going to be more specific with the errors in case...

```
a value of type "PWSTR" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "LPSTR"
cannot convert from 'PWSTR' to 'LPSTR'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert all of your projects to use the `UNICODE` setting. In this day and age, your application can be used by various people with various scripts and using UNICODE support is essential on Windows.

To do that, change the setting in the Visual Studio projects and fix all the errors. This will likely entail using `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`, `wchar_t *` instead of `char *`, and WinAPI types like `WCHAR`, `LPWSTR`, `LPCWSTR`, etc.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial thought. However, my application wouldnt really benefit from Unicode. I found this cheat sheet. Is it a good start to learn how to convert my code to Unicode? http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/c-unicode.html